# How to solve 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)' for a simple cnn model on images?

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I wanted to apply a simple cnn model on image datasets.

Model :

```
simple_model = nn.Sequential(
    nn.Conv2d(3, 8, kernel_size = 3, stride = 1, padding = 1),
    nn.MaxPool2d(2, 2)
)
```

and then I wanted to check the shape after modeling using the below code !

```
for images, labels in train_dl:
  print("Images shape: ", images.shape)
  out = simple_model(images)
  print("out shape: ", out.shape)
  break
```

but it is showing the following error !!

ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

How to solve this ?

I tried the above code, but the above error had occured !!

Comment: `train_dl` contains more than two elements in each row. You need to assign as many variables as there are elements.

Comment: How can I know how many elements does train_dl have ?

this is train_dl 

train_dl = DataLoader(train_ds, batch_size, shuffle = True, num_workers = 4, pin_memory = True)

Comment: You can try printing it. Or do `for row in train_dl: print(row)`

Comment: omg ! That's tooo many !!!

['y', 's', '2', '\\', 'T', '/', 'a', 'D', 'C', 'b', 's', 't', 'r', 'n', 'v', 'v', 't', 'D', 'e', 't', 'a', 'b', 'D', 'i', 'c', 'e', '2', 'i', '/', 'e', '0', 'D', 'o', 't', '1', 'Z', '8', 'a', 'i', 'o', 'i', 'r', '3', '9', 'e', 't', '_', '/', 'c', '-', 'e', '/', 'a', 'r', 'e', 'i', 't', ' ', '/', 'a', ' ', 'i', 'a', '0', 'o', 's', 'd', 'k', 'L', 't', 'N', 't', 'i', 's', 'r', 'n', 'o', 'a', '3', 'e', 'v', '-', 't', 'a', 't', '1', 'l', 'l', 'o']

Comment: So it's a list of characters. Why are you expecting it to contain an image and label?

Comment: yeah, now I get it ! It is showing the name of the directory, not images and labels !